# How to fix my code so that the list index is not out of range?

Tags: python

Essentially, all my examples are working except one. I don't know how to fix it.

```py
def get_nth_tweet(desiredpost: str, stringwanted: int) -> str:
    """This function should return the nth valid tweet in the sequence 
    of tweets.
    Precondition: n >= 0
    >>>get_nth_tweet('If the Easter Bunny and the Tooth Fairy had babies would they take your teeth and leave chocolate for you?', 0)
    return ('If the Easter Bunny and the Tooth Fairy had babies')
    >>>get_nth_tweet('If the Easter Bunny and the Tooth Fairy had babies would they take your teeth and leave chocolate for you?', 23)
    return (' ')
    """
    n = 50
    nth1 = [(desiredpost[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(desiredpost), n)]
    if stringwanted <= len(nth1):
        return nth1[stringwanted]
    else:
        return ' '
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x-wingide-python-shell://4600183936/2", line 46, in testGetNthTweet
  File "x-wingide-python-shell://4600183936/2", line 72, in _check
AssertionError: False is not true : The call get_nth_tweet(abcdef,1) caused an error: list index out of range

Comment: An index is in range when it is less than `<` the array length, not less-than-or-equal `<=`. The length of an array of ten items is 10; they are numbered from 0 to 9.

Answer (score -1):

Replace line 12 with

```
if stringwanted < len(nth1):
```